# How to get limited number of rows based on a DISTINCT values

Tags: sqlite

I have table like this

```
id | value |       date         |  for  | unit
----------------------------------------------
17 | 49.0 | 2021-02-22 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
29 | 49.0 | 2021-02-22 10:00:00 | Hip   | cm
14 | 49.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
16 | 48.0 | 2021-02-21 09:00:00 | Chest | cm
26 | 49.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Waist | cm
28 | 48.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Hip   | cm
27 | 48.0 | 2021-02-20 10:00:00 | Waist | cm
13 | 49.0 | 2021-02-06 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
25 | 49.0 | 2021-02-06 10:00:00 | Hip   | cm
12 | 48.0 | 2021-02-05 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
```

The result set should return:

```
id | value |       date         |  for  | unit
----------------------------------------------
17 | 49.0 | 2021-02-22 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
14 | 49.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Chest | cm
29 | 49.0 | 2021-02-22 10:00:00 | Hip   | cm
28 | 48.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Hip   | cm
26 | 49.0 | 2021-02-21 10:00:00 | Waist | cm
27 | 48.0 | 2021-02-20 10:00:00 | Waist | cm
```

This output contains 2 rows of each distinct values in 'for' column sorted desc by date

Comment: Please add column names to your sample table.

Comment: And what are the distinct columns?

Comment: Updated with column names.
'for' column for distinct values

Comment: Distinct what? Your expected results contain each value of `for` more than once.

Comment: Yes
I want each 'for'  containing 2 rows
If I failed to convey, Please check the expected result

Comment: Can you exaplain in detail how you separate id 16,15,13 and 12 for "Chest" example ?  14 and 16 have identical date.

Comment: Separated by limiting 2 of rows sorted desc by date , Sorry for 14 and 16 corrected it. Actually I only have expected result and want to know whether its possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to do with a [window function](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) like `row_number()` to rank each group, and then taking just the first two:

```sql
WITH ranked AS
  (SELECT id, value, date, for, unit,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY for ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable)
SELECT id, value, date, for, unit
FROM ranked
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY for, date DESC;
```

gives

```
id  value  date                 for    unit
--  -----  -------------------  -----  ----
17  49.0   2021-02-22 10:00:00  Chest  cm
14  49.0   2021-02-21 10:00:00  Chest  cm
29  49.0   2021-02-22 10:00:00  Hip    cm
28  48.0   2021-02-21 10:00:00  Hip    cm
26  49.0   2021-02-21 10:00:00  Waist  cm
27  48.0   2021-02-20 10:00:00  Waist  cm
```

For best results, add an index on `mytable(for, date DESC)` if this will be run frequently.

Comment: Can we do this without window functions?
Because old android versions doesn't support window functions @Shawn